# Inserting multiple new record same as existing records from same table with one column value changed

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have table in which I am storing records for lease contracts on a properties.Record is stored like this:

```
ID|PropertName|ContractStartDate|ContractEndDate|Status
 1| pqr     | 5/17/2012       | 5/17/2013     |leased
 2| xyz     | 10/25/2012      | 10/25/2013    |leased
 3| lmn     | 4/21/2012       | 4/21/2013     |leased   
 4| efg     | 4/22/2012       | 4/22/2013     |leased
```

Now I want to write store procedure which will check `ContractEndDate` with today's date and if it is expired then add new record in database having same values as previous record but status as expired.

this is how should my table will look like after that:

```
    ID|PropertName|ContractStartDate|ContractEndDate|Status
     1|   pqr     | 5/17/2012       | 5/17/2013     |leased
     2|   xyz     | 10/25/2012      | 10/25/2013    |leased
     3|   lmn     | 4/21/2012       | 4/21/2013     |leased   
     4|   efg     | 4/22/2012       | 4/22/2013     |leased
     5|   lmn     | 4/21/2012       | 4/21/2013     |expired
     6|   efg     | 4/22/2012       | 4/22/2013     |expired
```

I try to follow this post : [SQL to copy row and change 1 column value](http://forums.asp.net/t/1285371.aspx/1) but I get syntax error for select sub query.

Can I solve this using cursor and trigger? I have little knowledge of cursors and triggers so any samples like will be much appreciated. thanks

Comment: Presumably you want to avoid inserting such a row if one already exists with `expired`? Or is this not an issue?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes...

Comment: which is better approach insert...select or cursor...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE Cur CURSOR FOR
SELECT ID,PropertName,ContractStartDate,ContractEndDate,Status From TABLE_NAME

Open Cur
Declare @Id AS INT
DECLARE @PropertName AS VarChar(Max)
DECLARE @ContractStartDate AS DATETIME 
DECLARE @ContractEndDate AS DATETIME 
DECLARE @Status AS Varchar(80)
Fetch Next from Cur INTO @Id,@PropertName,@ContractStartDate,@ContractEndDate,@Status

While(@@fetch_status=0)
BEGIN
    IF(GETDATE() > @ContractEndDate)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @newID bigint 
        set @newID = (select max(ID) FROM TABLE_NAME)
        INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME(ID,PropertName,ContractStartDate,ContractEndDate,Status)
        VALUES (@newID+1,@PropertName,@ContractStartDate,@ContractEndDate,'expired' )
        Fetch Next from Cur INTO @Id,@PropertName,@ContractStartDate,@ContractEndDate,@Status   
    END
    Fetch Next from Cur INTO @Id,@PropertName,@ContractStartDate,@ContractEndDate,@Status   
END

Close Cur
Deallocate Cur
```

Comment: can I declare one variable for the all fields in record instead of different variable for each column

Comment: I think one variable is not enoughf for storing all values

Comment: I just missed the fetch statment inside update block thats why it go to infinite loop, i hope this code works try this ..............

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with cursor.

```
Step 1:  Open cursor with the select statement.(select * from table where ContractEndDate = sysdate)
Step 2: Loop the cursor
        Insert the values as 
        insert into table (ID,PropertName,ContractStartDate ,ContractEndDate,Status) values (newid, cursorVariable.PropertName,... , 'expired');

Step 3: End of the loop / with in the loop commit the transaction.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply `INSERT`.....`SELECT`. Assuming your `ID` is an `IDENTITY` column.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1(PropertName,ContractStartDate,ContractEndDate,Status)
SELECT PropertName, ContractStartDate, ContractEndDate, 'expired' 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE GETDATE() > CONTRACTENDDATE
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/90edf/2)